# Why is Scrapy not crawling/ parsing?

Tags: scrapy

This might be a repeat question. I am trying to run a Scrapy spider but unable to. Why do I get error message "HtmlResponse has no attribute urljoin"? What does Scrapy statistics imply if request_count is 3 and response_count is also 3?  My code is here. I would appreciate any help in this matter.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class BotSpider_2(BaseSpider):
    name = 'BotSpider_2'
    name = "google.co.th"
    start_urls = ["http://www.google.co.th/"]


    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        print sites
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your imports are incorrect. For example - why do you use `BaseSpider` instead of `Spider`? Also you didn't have import for `Selector`. Regarding `urljoin` error you described gettings I don't see the code you posted throwing this error; `urljoin` is an function of Response object since scrapy v1 or so which combines current url with some path to create absolute url that you can use to crawl.

```
$ scrapy shell "https://scrapy.org"
In [1]: response.url
Out[1]: 'https://scrapy.org'

In [2]: response.urljoin('/some/cool/path')
Out[2]: 'https://scrapy.org/some/cool/path'
```

I've cleaned up the imports and your code works like a charm!

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class BotSpider_2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "google.co.th"
    start_urls = ["http://www.google.co.th/"]


    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        print(sites)
```